# Get error after destroy action No Method Error in Controller#index, and log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nomethoderror

I have two models. **Hotel model:**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise ...
  has_many :hotels
end
```

**hotels_controller.rb**

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  def index   
    @hotels = current_user.hotels
  end

  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
  end

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])
    @hotel.user = current_user
    if @hotel.save
      redirect_to hotels_path, notice: "Nice, you added new hotel " + @hotel.title
    else
      render "new"
    end  
  end

  def edit
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    if @hotel.update_attributes(params[:hotel])
      redirect_to hotels_path, notice: "Hotel " + @hotel.title + " was successfully updated"
    else
      render "edit"
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.destroy
    redirect_to hotels_path, notice: "Hotel " + @hotel.title + " was deleted"
  end
end
```

When I signed in I'm creating hotel with some fields, after submit it's rederect me to a list of hotels and it's nice. But when I try to delete some of the hotels I get

```
NoMethodError in HotelsController#index

undefined method `hotels' for nil:NilClass
```

and after that when go to the home page(root) my session is over and user is logouted. But! Hotel was successfully destroyed. Something with index action... What i do wrong? Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in your layouts/application.html.erb this line in a head block

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that current_user is nil and failing when you try to get hotels on it.

```
current_user.hotels
```

So the question is: what sets up current_user?
You're using devise - can you check what you're doing on hotels-index? do you get automatically logged in for that or does it assume you're sometimes logged-in and sometimes not and it's failing to pick that up?

Comment: In hotels-index i go through hotels <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %> get hotel fields and add buttons like show/edit/delete. User must be signed in, after that he has a list of all users hotels and has only show action, when he add new hotel he rederected to index action with only his hotels and he can show edit and delete them

Comment: @yozzz you should really be checking `current_user` on every action; index should be unreachable when the user is logged out. Another thing to look for is that your form posts a CSRF token - if it is missing and forgery protection is enabled, the user's session will be cleared on a DELETE.

Comment: sounds like @zetetic has hit the nail on the head here. If the authenticity token is lost you'll lose your session and be logged out. Then there won't be a current-user when you get back to the index action.